# WCF, REST, SSL, Client, custom certificate validation

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl, client

I have a specific problem that I can't solve. Let me explain in detail. I'm new to this technology so I might be using some wrong terms. Please correct and explain or ask for explanation if you don't understand.
I am creating a self hosted WCF REST server, hosted in WPF application. It uses https, SLL with  WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport. I am using my own generated certificate. 
I would like to create a WinForms client that would use this service. The format of the response form the server is JSON. 
I would like to validate the certificate on the client with my custom validator inherited from X509CertificateValidator.

This is my server side code. I'm using a custom username validator that works fine. I have configured the certificate in the IIS Manager on my machine for the Default Website > Bindings, where I have generated the certificate (Windows 7).

```
WebServiceHost sh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ReachService)); 
string uri = "https://localhost:9000/Service"; 
WebHttpBinding wb = new WebHttpBinding(); 
wb.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport; 
wb.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IReachService), wb, uri);
sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserNameValidator();
sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;

sh.Open();
```

and this is my client code

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:9000/Service");
WebChannelFactory<ReachService> cf = new WebChannelFactory<IReachService>(uri);
WebHttpBinding wb = cf.Endpoint.Binding as WebHttpBinding;
wb.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
wb.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
cf.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
cf.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new CustomCertificateValidator("PL2"); // this is the name that issued the certificate
cf.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user1"; 
cf.Credentials.UserName.Password = "user1";
IReachService service = cf.CreateChannel();
try
{
  CustomersList auth = service.GetCustomers();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

on calling service.GetCustomers() I get:
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 
'localhost:9000'.
InnerException Message:
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
InnerException Message:
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

The server is working fine when I test in the browser. 
But the client code is wrong cause it doesn't go to the custom cert validator class. And this class is the same as in the MSDN example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator.aspx.

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong with this approach?

If you need more info please ask.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue occurs because certificate was issued for some other hostname. You can check this (and customize if necessary) by providing custom ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

Comment: I will look into this Konstantin cause I don't exactly know what you are referring to. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: just look for ServicePointManager class in MSDN or Google. It allows you to customize certificates validation and by providing your custom callback you can put a breakpoint there and see what errors were found by the default validation.

Comment: I believe Konstantin is referring to the server name in the certificate, which should match the hostname that you are connecting to (in this case, probably "localhost"). The server name appears in the certificate as the CN part of the Subject Name. Or, if that doesn't match (i.e., it's not "localhost") it can appear as an X509 V3 certificate extension "Subject Alternative Name" as a "DNS" name, which is something you can put in yourself if you are creating your own certificates with openssl, for example.

Answer (score 1):

//don't use HttpWebRequest --you lose all of the strongly-typed method and data contracts!

//the code to create the channel and call a method:

```
SetCertPolicy(); 
var cf1 = new WebChannelFactory<TService>(new Uri(remoteServiceAddressSecure));
var service = cf1.CreateChannel();
sevice.DoMethod();

protected static void SetCertPolicy()
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += RemoteCertValidate;
        }

private static bool RemoteCertValidate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain,
                SslPolicyErrors error)
        {
            // trust any cert!!!
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I know it's kind of a hack, and dangerous in production, but you just saved my day!

Comment: Please note that `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is a simple delegate property and not an event. And when concatenating delegates, only the return value of the last delegate will be used - all others will silently be discarded. Thus using `operator +=` makes no sense, you might as well just set it using `operator =`. Unfortunately there are a zillion incorrect examples floating around the Net, but that doesn't make it right :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WCF on the client, then don't use WebHttpBinding, stick with the SOAP stuff it will work much better.
However, if you want to use a standard HTTP client like, [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or [HttpClient V.prototype](http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2009/12/08/httpclient-the-basics/) or  [HttpClient V.Next](http://wcf.codeplex.com/) then stick with the webHttpBinding.

Sorry for not addressing your direct question but you are likely to run into more problems because you are using a binding that was intended to make WCF services accessible to non-WCF platforms but then using WCF to try and access it.

Comment: Hi Darrel, thanks for your answer. I am using WebHttpBinding so I can support multiple types of clients on mobile platforms (i.e. Win7, Android, iPhone) with this server in future. I wanted to create the WinForms client first to understand what I need to do.

Comment: @elector That's cool.  Just make sure you use a standard HTTP client instead of the WCF Channels.  That way your clients across the different platforms will work more consistently.

Comment: Thanks Darrel, that sounds cool but I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by standard http client? :) Do you know of an example in c# quickly? Or just what should I google for? As I say, I'm new to this so every bit of info helps a lot.

Comment: I think he means HttpWebRequest, but there is usually no much sense in using it instead of WCF.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, thank you for your answer. I googled a bit and also found HttpWebRequest. I think this is what Darrel means. And perhaps it makes sense to use it so porting the code to other languages is easier.