# Does WCF do CRL/OCSP certificate checking?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, x509certificate, ocsp

We are working on a payment processing application and want to make sure we are doing CRL/OCSP checks when establishing secure connections (we will be initiating a TLS 1.1 session with a server). I would think that .NET would do this for us, but I'm not able to find any information in this regard.

1. Does .NET do this auto-magically?
2. Are there any settings to control how it works?
3. Please provide links to documentation that I cannot seem to find.
4. If it does not do this for us. Is there a 'best-practice' method for performing the checks, such as the `X509Certificate2.Verify` Method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes, by default WCF client do check server certificate to determine if it is valid for requested usage and is not revoked.
2. yes, you can control certificate validation behavior. These threads discuss the subject:

One: [WCF, REST, SSL, Client, custom certificate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759217/wcf-rest-ssl-client-custom-certificate-validation)

Two: [Custom WCF client certificate over ssl validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966576/custom-wcf-client-certificate-over-ssl-validation)

Answer (score 2):

The best link I know of is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702579.aspx

According to that link, when using HTTPS, WCF checks the chain trust but does not check for revocation. For Message based security and for TLS over TCP, WCF does both checks according to the the client endpoint configuration.